# Trying to validate a input text box but element lacks displayed text

Tags: automated-testing

I am working on some automation tests and have gotten to a wall. When the page is loaded, a call is made to get data to prefill input fields from what I can tell.

Here is the element that I'm checking(Goal is get the prefilled text from the `input type="text" name="tempname"` to validate it is correct):

```
<div class="twelve columns">
          <label for="tempname">Template Name <span class="compulsion"> *</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="tempname" id="tempname">
          <h4 class="notice fielderror"></h4>
</div>
```

Typically in my Selenium test, I would return the element and use `getAttribute()` or `getText()` to return what I'm looking for and use an `assertTrue` or `assertEquals`.

I can't figure out how to get the text that is displayed within this element to validate it. Any ideas/tips would be really helpful!

Side note: I am using Selenium for my automation tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this approach?

`element = FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id='tempname']"))`
`string = element.getAttribute("value")`

This `string` should have what you want.

Comment: Ahh thank you for this! `.getAttribute("value")` seemed to be exactly what I was looking for. 

Since this element doesn't have a `value=` attribute, why does it return correctly?

Comment: @Jordan, look it up on the internet, "value" is hidden